# How do I trim multiple lines in the same Google Sheet/Excel cell?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How do I trim multiple lines in a single cell in Google Sheets?

I am able to trim the first line using the following:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(K2,FIND("        ",K2)))
```

Here is an example of a cell of my data:

```
(253) 473-2043        (PT) (L) (100%) [Feedback]
(720) 242-9015        (MT) (L) (100%) [Feedback]
(720) 413-6453        (MT) (M) (86%) [Feedback]
(253) 209-6014        (PT) (M) (66%) [Feedback]
(253) 471-7777        (PT) (66%) [Feedback]
(706) 414-0490        (ET) (M) (66%) [Feedback]
(706) 471-7777        (ET) (M) (66%) [Feedback]
(706) 560-1682        (ET) (66%) [Feedback]
(509) 838-3878        (PT) (3%) [Feedback]
(706) 793-2936        (ET) (3%) [Feedback]
```

This is all contained within one cell. I only need the first 14 characters (phone number) of each line. I'm only able to extract the first line using the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(?m)(\d)( .*)$","$1")
```

Comment: So this works only on the first few rows - I have 1,000 rows that I need to apply this to, how do I do this?

Comment: It randomly works for different data sets and doesn't work for others - is there a long load time or something?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a lot simpler with  the right regex but this seems to work:

```
=transpose(ArrayFormula(replace(left(split(substitute(A1,") ",")"),char(10)),13),5,1,") ")))
```

Comment: Excellent job! However, how do I get it to print the results in one cell instead of multiple?

Answer (score 0):

This works as well:

=JOIN(" ",ARRAYFORMULA(trim(SPLIT(A1,CHAR(10)))))